# Java, Telnet, check for String in an InputStream

Tags: java, inputstream, telnet, outputstream

I am fairly raw.  I am trying to write a Java class to interact with Telnet.  I saw that Apache Commons and Jsacpe had APIs.  I am using Jscape's Sinetfactory.  The Telnet I am connecting to sends a prompt to enter 'User name?:' as soon as telnet.connect() occurs.  I am required to verify that this prompt is actually happening so I do not just write the answer when something else may happen.  I am inexperienced with this and am sure there is a simple answer, just wondering if anyone might be able to help.

Here is what I have, its a bit sloppy because I've been playing around for awhile not sure how to actually read the last characters from the stream.

```
import com.jscape.inet.telnet.*;

public class TelnetTest extends TelnetAdapter {

    private final static String USER = "xxx\r";
    private final static String PWORD = "yyy\r";
    private final static String COMMAND = "zzz\r";
    private final static byte[] USER_BYTE = USER.getBytes();
    private final static byte[] PWORD_BYTE = PWORD.getBytes();
    private final static byte[] COMMAND_BYTE = COMMAND.getBytes();
    private Telnet telnet = null;
    private OutputStream output = null;
    private static BufferedReader reader = null;
    private boolean connected = false;
    private String hostname = "qqq";
    //TelnetInputStream tis = null; NOT IN USE AS OF NOW

    public TelnetTest() throws IOException, TelnetException {

        // create new Telnet instance
        telnet = new Telnet(hostname);

        // register this class as TelnetListener
        telnet.addTelnetListener(this);

        // establish Telnet connection
        telnet.connect();
        connected = true;
        output = telnet.getOutputStream();

// HERE IS WHERE I NEED HELP, NOT SURE HOW TO CHECK STREAM
        String str = null;
        if ((str = reader.readline()).equals("User name?:")) {
            telnet.getOutputStream().write(USER_BYTE);
        }
// SAME CHECK WOULD HAPPEN HERE FOR "Password"
        telnet.getOutputStream().write(PWORD_BYTE);
//  ANOTHER SIMILAR CHECK HERE
        telnet.getOutputStream().write(COMMAND_BYTE);

        // sends all data entered at console to Telnet server
        String input = null;
        while ((input = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (connected) {
                ((TelnetOutputStream) output).println(input);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean streamContainsString(Reader reader, String searchString)
            throws IOException {
        Scanner streamScanner = new Scanner(reader);
        if (streamScanner.findWithinHorizon(searchString, 0) != null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Invoked when Telnet socked is connected.
    public void connected(TelnetConnectedEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Connected");
    }

    // Invoked when Telnet socket is disconnected. Disconnect can
    public void disconnected(TelnetDisconnectedEvent event) {
        connected = false;
        System.out.print("Disconnected.  Press enter key to quit.");
    }

    // Invoked when Telnet server requests that the Telnet client begin performing               specified TelnetOption.
    public void doOption(DoOptionEvent event) {
        // refuse any options requested by Telnet server
        telnet.sendWontOption(event.getOption());
    }

    // Invoked when Telnet server offers to begin performing specified TelnetOption.
    public void willOption(WillOptionEvent event) {
        // refuse any options offered by Telnet server
        telnet.sendDontOption(event.getOption());
    }

    // Invoked when data is received from Telnet server.
    public void dataReceived(TelnetDataReceivedEvent event) {
        // print data recevied from Telnet server to console
        System.out.print(event.getData());
    }

    public Telnet getTelnet() {
        return telnet;
    }

    // starts console program
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // create BufferedReader to read data from console
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            // create new TelnetExample instance
            TelnetTest example = new TelnetTest();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont understand what you mean by "verify that this prompt is actually happening."  would this entail showing the username after connection or checking that the user actually entered something as opposed to leaving it blank?

Comment: I mean to make sure that telnet is actually asking for "User name?", "Password:" and "ComputerName:/h0>" opposed to some other text telnet might be waiting for.  This is not likely but seems to be good practice and helps avoid sleep() if things are moving too slowly and the prompt is not in the stream by the time the code checks for it.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Was my answer at all helpful @MikeNick?  Please accept if so.

Answer (score 4):

If you are reading/writing Strings then you should always use `Reader` and `Writer`.  `BufferedReader` allows you to do line operations.  So a `BufferedReader` wrapped around an `Reader` (around a `InputStreamReader`) will allow you to do a `readLine()` call to get the line of input from the connection:

```
 BufferedReader reader =
     new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(telnet.getInputStream()));
```

To write to the connection you would use a `Writer` around a `OutputStreamWriter`:

```
 Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(telnet.getOutputStream()));
```

I'm not sure if that works with the stream from `Telnet` but it works with a raw `Socket`.  You then could do something like the following pseudo code:

```
 while (true) {
     read a line from the server
     some sort of if/then/else to test for the output
     write your username/password or whatever is appropriate for the connection
     repeat until some logout or IOException...
 }
```

The Apache `Telnet` class has a number of interesting listeners and other handlers which you could use if you wanted to but the learning curve may be more.  Here's a good sample application using `TelnetClient`:

> http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/ExampleofuseofTelnetClient.htm